# Strange shadowing after optimising mesh vertices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, vertices

I'm generating a custom mesh out of a height map, and it works fine, except that after generating the mesh, there are a lot of duplicated vertices; duplicated in the sense that they occupy the same point in space.

In an attempt to optimise this, I run thru all of them and detect the ones in the same space and remove the duplication, and recalculate all the triangles.

This yields the same mesh, but now with 1 fifth of the vertices, the exact desired result.

However, in the unity editor, the visual changes. Some strange shadowing appears after I have optimised the mesh. See screenshots below.

This screenshot is before optimising the mesh.

[image: BEFORE optimisation]

This screenshot is the exact same mesh, but now with optimised vertices.

[image: AFTER the optimisation has run]

What can be the cause of this? I assume it's being done by the lightning of the scene, but no changes to the lighting has been made between the two screenshots.

Comment: It's probably due to soft shadow settings. In specific light under "Shadow type" select: No shadows and see if you fix this issue.

Comment: Hi - yes, you're right, it's the shadowing that is causing this. But why though?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured it out. In optimising the mesh, I removed all overlapping vertices, but then I loose the hard edging, since every vertices only have one normal which is shared bu several triangles.

When the vertices are shared, the normal is interpolated across faces. I bet that is what is causing this effect.